# Vuetify grid system does not allow different order in nested grid

Tags: vuetify.js

I saw the nested grid example in https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid#nested-grid.
However I need some different layout, and the order should change in different breakpoints.

Desired layouts:

- md and up: https://codepen.io/jcpribeiro/pen/NJReGm
- sm and down: https://codepen.io/jcpribeiro/pen/gEPEOj

Note that the order is different.

In another example I could use have different orders in different layouts using `order-xs1` (see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/grid#order), but `v-flex` items in nested grids do not belong all to the same `v-layout` item, so it will not work the same way.

I would like to avoid moving items with javascript.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: If anyone was looking for different `order` for RWD, then `order-sm="1"`/`order-sm="2"`/... on `<v-col>` works. I think that's not an answer for this question, but I was actually looking for `order` on different screen sizes and this question popped up.

PS. I do exclude the old approach relying on `<v-layout>`/`<v-flex>`  and `order-xs1`/`order-xs2` on `<v-flex>`. Couldn't find the new way to handle this relying on `<v-row>`/`<v-col>`, that was my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since order is different I would apply a v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp" on one layout and a v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown" on the other.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/breakpoints#breakpoints

As an example:

```
<v-layout v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp" row wrap>
  1st set of flex items in here        
</v-layout>
<v-layout v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown" row wrap>
  2nd set flex items in here        
</v-layout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Do you mean duplicating one of the elements?

Comment: The text can be interpolated from data to keep the code DRY.  If the layouts are large...consider creating two components.

Comment: I was hoping to get a better solution, but if there is no better solution, I will accept this one.

Comment: You could set classes on the elements and tie them to a switch statement.  For example :class='computedProperty' and then use a switch that changes the order dependent on the viewport size.  That can get involved but would be another option...check out the [Switch Example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/breakpoints#breakpoints)